`grep: /var/log/syslog: binary file matches` should I be worried?
I was just trying to grep syslog when I hit:
$ grep -E 'Sep.*EXT4' /var/log/syslog
[... some data ...]
grep: /var/log/syslog: binary file matches

EDIT: first attempt used cmp and strings, but that gives wrong results for UTF-8.
$ \zgrep -C 2 -Pan '\x00' /var/log/syslog* |  cat -vET
/var/log/syslog.1-8236-Sep 23 11:59:12 jakub-Latitude-5431 rtkit-daemon[1824]: Successfully made thread 11652 of process 6125 owned by '1000' RT at priority 10.$
/var/log/syslog.1-8237-Sep 23 11:59:12 jakub-Latitude-5431 rtkit-daemon[1824]: Supervising 10 threads of 7 processes of 1 users.$
/var/log/syslog.1:8238:^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@Sep 23 12:03:51 jakub-Latitude-5431 systemd-modules-load[915]: Inserted module 'lp'$
/var/log/syslog.1-8239-Sep 23 12:03:51 jakub-Latitude-5431 systemd-modules-load[915]: Inserted module 'ppdev'$
/var/log/syslog.1-8240-Sep 23 12:03:51 jakub-Latitude-5431 lvm[907]:   2 logical volume(s) in volume group "vgubuntu" monitored$
/var/log/syslog.2.gz-19151-Sep 13 17:13:03 jakub-Latitude-5431 kernel: [371517.143856] audit: type=1400 audit(1726240383.797:15759): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/etc/fstab" pid=389526 comm="firefox" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0$
/var/log/syslog.2.gz-19152-Sep 13 17:13:03 jakub-Latitude-5431 kernel: [371517.149625] audit: type=1400 audit(1726240383.802:15760): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/etc/fstab" pid=389526 comm="firefox" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0$
/var/log/syslog.2.gz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ep 13 17:31:40 jakub-Latitude-5431 systemd-modules-load[981]: Inserted module 'lp'$
/var/log/syslog.2.gz-19154-Sep 13 17:31:40 jakub-Latitude-5431 systemd-modules-load[981]: Inserted module 'ppdev'$
/var/log/syslog.2.gz-19155-Sep 13 17:31:40 jakub-Latitude-5431 systemd-modules-load[981]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'$

I'm not sure what happened here? I don't think it's normal for syslog to contain binary characters.

/var/log/syslog.2.gz is a compressed file so the result is meaningless. Use zgrep if you want to look into its contents

I did do exactly that, now changed to \zgrep per your other comment

You should show more context around the byte with null bytes zgrep -C 2 -Pan '\x00' /var/log/syslog*

updated to add the context lines

The invalid character is the null byte here
... QVariant(QByteArray, "/home/jakub/Downloads\x00")) ...


My bad, the null byte is actually at another position. "/home/jakub/Downloads\x00" is still a bug in the program that printed the log, but it's irrelevant to the null byte in your syslog file
Here you used strings which is the wrong tool to detect null bytes because GNU strings only work with ASCII characters by default. You can easily verify that
$ printf "Panzerjäger\nHello\nW\0rld\nSchön\nInvalid UTF-8 \342\313 string\n" | strings
Panzerj
Hello
Invalid UTF-8
 string
$ printf "Panzerjäger\nHello\nW\0rld\nSchön\nInvalid UTF-8 \342\313 string\n" | strings -e S
Panzerjäger
Hello
Schön
Invalid UTF-8 �� string

xxd -p -l3 -s 249932 /var/log/syslog returns c3a467 which is the encoding of äg in Panzerjäger, which is the first non-printable character according to strings when it uses the 7-bit ASCII encoding. -e S specifies an 8-bit encoding and can print the characters with the high bit set. BSD strings uses the 8-bit encoding by default so you'll get Panzerjäger instead of Panzerj
grep will report binary file matches if it sees a file with (1) null bytes, or (2) invalid byte sequences in the current locale's encoding. Since most locales nowadays use UTF-8, you can easily check the (2) case with any text processing tools in Linux1. The simplest method is to use grep -axv '.*' your/log/file
$ printf "Panzerjäger\nHello\nW\0rld\nSchön\nInvalid UTF-8 \342\313 string\n" | grep -axv '.*'
Invalid UTF-8 �� string

However those methods won't report null bytes, because they're valid in UTF-8 and pretty much any other encodings out there. To look for (1) lines containing null bytes you'll need some other solutions:
$ printf "Panzerjäger\nHello\nW\0rld\nSchön\nInvalid UTF-8 \342\313 string\n" | \grep -Pan '\x00' | cat -vET
3:W^@rld$

grep -n will print out the line number containing the null byte (3), and cat -vET will print it in escaped form for easier reading, so you can just use \grep -Pan '\x00' your/log/file | cat -vET

There are 2 possible reasons for the null bytes to appear

The system was shutdown abruptly so there was no chance to flush the buffer. I regularly see this on my embedded SBCs. There'll be lots of null bytes between the last flushed log line and the next boot up log. But it doesn't look like that's the case in your output
The string actually contains embedded nulls. QString can do that just like std::string, so if the string was read incorrectly with the final null byte or the null byte was inserted somehow then it'll be printed out in the log. It's a bug but for now it doesn't harm

Either case it's not quite an issue yet. Usually you'll want to use grep -a for searching logs to avoid messages like this

1 See also

How can I get Perl to detect bad UTF-8 sequences?
How to write a check in python to see if file is valid UTF-8?
How to detect invalid utf8 unicode/binary in a text file


Yeah, I noticed that, but I wasn't sure if it's a \x00 literal string or an escape sequence. So I this is an escaped null char.

Though, why is cmp telling me it's byte 249933 that looks to be a4 byte?

@JakubBochenski I made a mistake, please check my update

\grep looks like a typo?

Updated my question, now it looks like there is a whole bunch of null characters as would be expected in case 1.

@JakubBochenski no, that's an explicit backslash to avoid possible aliases that set --color=always. An alternative is grep -Pan '\x00' --color=never | cat
